# Audio fading in and out on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04

Tags: sound, ubuntu-gnome

The title says it all. Whether I am listening to audio, watching a video, or watching YouTube, the audio will drop to being barely audible for anywhere from 30 seconds to 5 or 6 minutes, then it will quickly fade back up to the pre-selected audio level.

Where do I begin to troubleshoot this?

Thanks!

Comment: Might be related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1115079/134205