# Why does Audio fade-in instead of starting at set volume level?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, hdmi, audio-sync

- Ubuntu 18.04.01
- HDMI from GPU to the Asus monitor speakers (volume
  set to 100 within the monitor's menu)

When, for example, I start a YouTube video the video starts playing but, the audio slowly comes online. That is, it goes from zero volume and slowly progresses, fades-in, up to the volume I actually have set (about 50%). It's like there is a dial being turned.

Instead, I'd like the audio to immediately come online when I start a video at the volume I have set.

Audio works fine otherwise, it's only when it starts that it transitions in slowly. Happens every time I pause and play a video again. Audio slowly comes online.

Not sure what would cause this. I checked monitor for settings and it only has the volume. I checked Ubuntu sound settings and don't see anything there. I checked in YouTube as well Firefox settings and see nothing there either. Not sure where else to look. I also checked out `alsamixer` too.

Comment: Same problem here. You are not crazy! :) Did you ever find a solution? As a workaround, I found leaving pavucontrol open temporarily fixes this, presumably by keeping the relevant audio interface powered / alive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is due to pulseaudio suspending the respective audio interface, presumably for power saving reasons.

Try editing your pulse audio config (for me /etc/pulse/default.pa) and comment out this line to disable this feature:

```
load-module module-suspend-on-idle
```

Then restart Pulseaudio:

```
pulseaudio -k
```

Comment: Thanks Dane! I just realized this only happens when using my Asus VH236h monitor speakers via HDMI. I tried your fix using headphones direct to the PC and that's when I realized the headphones were working as expected, until I switched to the HDMI and it had the same issue. It was the same with your fix or without. I suppose I'll have to search out for help for the monitor instead of something with Ubuntu instead. I'll leave this as is should others find this helpful or in case it was still related after all.

Comment: Now I need to figure out if it's the Asus VH236h, the HDMI cable, or the ASUS Strix GEFORCE GTX 960 or some combination. Sound works fine, it's just a slight 5 or 10 second delay before sound comes up to volume.

Comment: Thank you Dane! This was the issue I was having.

Comment: Trying to solve this 2 years and 8 months later, now on Manjaro, it would appear stumbling on my own question has proven useful. This fix seems to have solved the issue with my VH236h monitor audio. Thanks again Dane!

Comment: Some tips on editing the configuration files that should be considered with this answer, "It is strongly suggested not to edit system-wide configuration files, but rather edit user ones. Create the ~/.config/pulse directory, then copy the system configuration files into it and edit according to your need." https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio#Configuration_files